# Regex to find named XML tags which may be empty

Tags: regex

I have problem to find specific named xml tags within a text block which may or may not be empty. I am not sure if the problem is after all resolvable with regex.

For example I have the following text block:

```
...<item name="xxx">yyyy</item>....
```

To filter out the 'item' tag with its attributes I a use the following regex:

```
<item(.*?)>(.*?)</item>|<item(.*?)./>
```

This regex also works with empty tags like in the following example text:

```
...<item name="zzz" />....
```

My problem is that my text contains multiple 'item' tags. This works as long as I do not mix the empty with not-empty tags like in the following example textblock:

```
...<item name="zzz" />....
...<item name="xxx">yyyy</item>....
```

The regex I use did not work with this siutation as it finds the first result:

```
<item name="zzz" />.......<item name="xxx">yyyy</item>
```

My question is: Is this problem solveable with regex? 
My first thougt was to use kind of "AND NOT" combination like

```
(<item(.*?))(?!/>)>(.*?)</item>
```

But I failed at the problem.

My Java Code to apply the regex to a given textblock looks like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<item(.*?)>(.*?)</item>|<item(.*?)./>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textblock);
while (matcher.find()) {
   String attributes = matcher.group(1);
   ....
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an XML parser? Note that parsing XML/HTML using regex [is generally not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4934172).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - ok I almost guessed that this cannot be resolved sensibly with a Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will work if using tag attributes regex as defined by the w3c
you can get 100% accuracy in finding open and self-contained tags.

But, you need an engine that uses atomic groups you can also differentiate
between open and self contained as below:

Raw:

```
(?s)(?:(<item(?>\b(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)*>)(?<=/>))|(<item(?>\b(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)*>)(?<!/>))(.*?)(</item\s*>))
```

Double quoted:

```
"(?s)(?:(<item(?>\\b(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)*>)(?<=/>))|(<item(?>\\b(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)*>)(?<!/>))(.*?)(</item\\s*>))"
```

https://regex101.com/r/R3iVVW/1

```
 (?s)
 (?:
      (                                    # (1 start), Self Contained item
           <item
           (?>                                  # Atomic to trap self contained
                \b  
                (?: " .*? " | ' .*? ' | [^>]*? )*
                > 
           )
           (?<= /> )                            # Must be a self contained item

      )                                    # (1 end)

   |                                     # OR, 

      (                                    # (2 start), Open item
           <item
           (?>                                  # Atomic to trap self contained
                \b 
                (?: " .*? " | ' .*? ' | [^>]*? )*
                >
           )
           (?<! /> )                            # Not a self contained item
      )                                    # (2 end)
      ( .*? )                              # (3), Item content
      ( </item \s* > )                     # (4), Close item
 )
```

Benchmarked:

```
Regex1:   (?s)(?:(<item(?>\b(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)*>)(?<=/>))|(<item(?>\b(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)*>)(?<!/>))(.*?)(</item\s*>))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   14
Elapsed Time:    4.73 s,   4728.21 ms,   4728214 µs
Matches per sec:   148,047
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The problem is that the order of the item tags can change.

Comment: The problem seems to be in java only. Your first example works fine on regex101.com. But it does not work in Java using a java.util.regex.Matcher. So I change my code by simply parsing the content manually.
I compile the pattern in java using the Pattern.DOTALL option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This regex is impressive! and it works in all my scenarios (I have a lot of junit tests)